# Exporting and Importing configuration setting only

Tags: 8, configuration

I have a development and a production site. Both are working in an offline environment, Drush and Composer are not installed.

The plan is to make all changes always on the development and during each "release" to simply synchronize the changes on the production site.

Currently this is working fine via UI  "Configuration Synchronization -> Import/Export " feature.

But I would like to execute this on the command level ( Linux ) and as it was mentioned, no drush is installed.

**Question:**
Is it possible to export just the CONFIG Table from MySQL database and import this on the production site? Would this be similar to the Import/Export mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing configuration in SQL alone is not possible, you need to run PHP code.

From the command line, if you don't have Drush installed, you can download Drush on the fly and execute the import command:

```
wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.1.17/drush.phar
php drush.phar config-import
```